# CollectionView image downloaded in albums is the same for all CollectionViewCells

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

When I download albums via internet, it creates some folders with a cover image in it. When I want to display that image in a collectionView, it displays always the same image for all albums. For example, if I download album 1, album 2, album 3 with respectively cover.png in ablum 1, cover.png in ablum2, cover.png in album3.

Here is the code : (I precise that for tests, if I use images that are coming from an array with images in the bundle, it works).

```
#pragma mark - Collection View
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [[DBManagement database] getNBDownloadedAlbums: [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"SettingsWebview"]];
}


- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *identifier = @"cell";

    AlbumsController *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (!cell)
    {
        cell = [[AlbumsController alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,cell.frame.size.width , cell.frame.size.height)];
    }

    NSString * coverImagePath = [[[[albums objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"URL"] stringByDeletingLastPathComponent] stringByAppendingString:@"/cover.png"];
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:coverImagePath])
    {
        NSLog(@"Cover : perso");
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:coverImagePath];
        cell.label.text = coverImagePath;
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Cover : generique");
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"nocover.png"];
        cell.label.text = @"nocover.png";
    }

    return cell;
}

- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return CGSizeMake(200, 155);
}
-(UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section
{
    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(5, 5, 5, 5);
}
```

**EDIT:**
When I do it step by step, it seems that line is not doing the job :

```
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:coverImagePath];
```

doesn't load the good image. I don't understand because when I read the coverImagePath, the name is good, the cover is the good image because I check with the iexplorer directly on the ipad, but the image load into the imageView.image is not good. It is always the first image that is repeating on every cell Views even if the name is correct. Strange.

**2nd EDIT:**
For your info, the name of the images cover are the same in each folder cover.png, is it the problem ?

Comment: do you have a single cell for every row in your CollectionView?

Comment: Yep, I have only one cell that is called "cell".

Comment: You should NSlog the values from indexPath.row in order to see if it returns everytime different values based on the amount of rows in your CollectionView, I had a similar problem and I just had to use indexPath.section, because my CollectionView had N section each one with just 1 row, so using indexPath.row always returned 1

Comment: I check that part and the values for Indexpath.row, and the name of the image is good. It is like a problem of cache, as if the image is not erased and duplicate in every cell... For info, I have only one section

Comment: @Claudio why don't you try to give different names for you cover images ? More likely this is a caching issue.

Comment: That's what I have done, it works. Sometimes, that objective C and Xcode have limits! Thx dude.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*1st correction* : I used different names for the covers images and it works now. I think Xcode and Objective C doesn't manage very well when displaying several cells images coming from different folders but with the same name (for example cover.png. Instead of, I put cover_album1.png, cover_album2.png, etc...).

*2nd correction* : I precise that I had to add the following code for renew the images of the collection view :

in the CollectionViewCell.m

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self)
    {
        self.imageView = [UIImageView new];
    }
    return self;
}
```

I precise that if you use a collectionView with the storyboard, you have to use **initWithCoder** instead of **initWithFrame**.